# Правописание "не" с прилагательным

Tags: орфография, прилагательные, частица-не

У меня есть предложение, примерно, следующее:

***Актёрское мастерство — это умение передавать существующие, но не доступные зрителю положения так, чтобы он сам сумел их прочувствовать.***

Долго искал в интернете, но до сих пор не могу быть абсолютно уверенным в написании частицы "не" с прилагательным "доступные" в данном случае. Можно ли допустить обоюдное написание?
В каких именно случаях "не" отделяется от слова мне ясно, но хотелось бы удостовериться в точности. Лично мне кажется, что раздельное написание подчёркивает, что определённые положения недоступны временно, по некоторым причинам. А что вы думаете?
И ещё одно уточнение: нужно ли ставить запятую перед словом "так", отделяя уточнение о недоступности?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Актёрское мастерство ― это умение передавать существующие, но *недоступные зрителю* положения так, чтобы он сам сумел их прочувствовать.**

А. Лучше использовать слитное написании НЕ по ряду причин:

1) **В словаре это слово дается с несколькими значениями, и они уже учитывают возможное наличие зависимых слов**, например: НЕДОСТУПНЫЙ. 4. Слишком трудный **для понимания, усвоения**, не поддающийся восприятию, переживанию **кого-л**. Н-ые рядовому читателю философские мысли.  Всё это недоступно женскому уму.  Любовь недоступна твоему пониманию.

2) **Правила допускают раздельное написание НЕ только как исключение** (наш вариант сюда не подходит):
[§66. Правописание не с именами прилагательными](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/38.htm#%D0%B7_04)

а) при прилагательных, которые в полной и краткой форме имеют разное значение (см. ниже п. 8), например: не готовый к выходу актер, не склонный к простуде ребенок;

б) иногда при постановке прилагательного с зависимыми словами **после определяемого существительного** (в условиях обособления конструкция с прилагательным приближается по значению к причастному обороту); ср.: шахматист играл в несвойственном ему стиле – черты, не свойственные нашей молодежи.

3) **В Нацкорпусе чаще встречается слитное написание** (350:20), причем раздельное написание используется обычно в обособленных оборотах: ...на стене ― инструкции и графики, глазу Андрея **не доступные**...  [Анатолий Азольский, 1998].

4) **Смысловое значение форм практически тождественно:** отрицается доступность или утверждается недоступность. Прилагательные не имеют значения времени, как причастия, поэтому не могут обозначить "временную недоступность".

Б. **ТАК, ЧТОБЫ или ТАК ЧТОБЫ** (ответ исправлен)

Актёрское мастерство — это умение передавать существующие, но не доступные зрителю положения так, чтобы он сам сумел их прочувствовать.

В данном предложении используется сочетание ТАК, ЧТОБЫ, то есть  **местоименно-союзная связь** (содержание указательного слова ТАК, отнесенного к глаголу, раскрывается с помощью союза ЧТОБЫ через следствие, обозначенное в придаточном).
Расчленение союзного выражения на местоименную часть и союз в данном случае более уместно, чем использование союза ТАК ЧТОБЫ.

Сравнить: По моей живости и непреодолимому безотчетному желанию передавать другим свои впечатленья **с точностию и ясностью очевидности**, так чтобы слушатели получили такое же понятие об описываемых предметах, какое я сам имел о них...

В этом примере в главном предложении уже присутствует обстоятельство (с точностию и ясностью очевидности), поэтому используется **составной союз ТАК ЧТОБЫ.**

Comment: так чтобы
союз; местоимение + союз
1. Союз. То же, что «для того чтобы». Синтаксические конструкции, начинающиеся с союза «так чтобы», выделяются знаками препинания (запятыми)...
2. Местоимение + союз.http://punktuaciya.academic.ru/691/%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, я постаралась учесть ее в ответе.